# Framework: how to reuse functions in the core framework? javascript in this case

Tags: javascript, frameworks

In a js framework there is a little problem: I want to reuse the code in the framework and outside it but it gets complicated;

when you want to add any klasses or helper functions it's done like this

```
 TStore.add({
      path: 'isArray',
      uses: ['inArray', 'someThingElse'],
      fn: function(l /*lib reference*/, u /* uses reference */){
           return function(array, item){
                /* stuff that calculates the array */
                return true; /* or false */
           }
      }
 })
```

now the problem is that when you call the method on TStore.add(...), this function will use the "inArray" that is the above function; I would like to reuse that code, instead of writing another time the same thing.

EDIT:
The TStore.add method explanation

```
 TStore.add = function(o){
      (...)
      // here I need to use the "inArray" function
      // but I haven't it yet!
      // ex:
      var uses = o.uses;
      if(this('isArray', uses)){
           // do something
           // but "isArray" is not available before
           // I don't add it like this: TStore.add({...})
           // like the 1º script, above
      }
 }
```

I think a lot of software (low level) finds this problem and is already solved, but I can't find a stable solution.

Comment: I'm note sure I understand your question. Can you elaborate a little more or make it more clear?

Comment: updated, check it. is more understandable?

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: Im creating one, so is not known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this problem could be solved by adding an extra layer of logic before you define
TStore.add

Comment: but this is the lower layer :s how might I do it?

Comment: I might not be understanding your question right. Is the behaviour of something like require.js satisfy what you are trying to build?

Comment: No. What Im trying to build is something similar to yui, gwt, dojo, because none of them have what I need. It's a UI application framework + library.

Comment: Try graphing the dependencies of your functions. You might have a circular reference in your logic that you will need to fix up. The dependency graph can help you determine the order to register your functions

Comment: "TStore.add" needs the "isArray", but in order to be able to use "isArray" bust be added with the "TStore.add" function.